# <input> losing focus

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've created a table with a PHP `foreach` loop; now I'm trying to replace the value inside `td` with an `input` when clicked.

```
$('#memberTable tr td').click(function(e){
    $(this).html('<input type="text" id="" size="20" value=""/>');
});
```

The input style just blinks once on `:focus` and then it loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it focused with `.focus()`:

```
$('#memberTable tr td').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();

    $('<input />', {
        type: 'text',
        id: '',
        size: 20,
        value: $this.text()
    }).appendTo($this).focus();
});
```

Comment: it's just showing the style with `focus()`, typing doesn't work

Comment: @NestedWeb: Works just fine for me (with a slight change): http://jsfiddle.net/S4PVY/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try focusing it manually:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" id="" size="20" value="" />');

$(this).empty().append(input);

input.focus();
```